# What is the Capture Level of Hungri-la Bird?

Tags: one-piece, toriko

I'm watching One Piece anime ep. 492.
There were Capture Levels for each animal shown on the screen subtitled, but the Capture Level of Hungri-la Birds was missing.

What is the Capture Level of Hungri-la Birds?

Comment: According to Toriko-wiki it is 3: http://toriko.wikia.com/wiki/Hungry-la_Bird

Comment: Make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [**Toriko wiki**](http://toriko.wikia.com/wiki/Hungry-la_Bird) its Capture Level is 3.

[image: Pic]